# Search and Sort Filter

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Search filter is not applied for searching element multiple times using Enter key . Works fine when searched one at a time.
For eg: If I search letter 'A' in a particular column , the output should be data containing 'A' in it. But when I backspace 'A'& search some other letter in the same column it refilters the previous list which shouldn't be the case. For every search it needs to filter from the original list and not the already filtered list.

I have tried using executeOnEnter & keyup.

```js
vm.filterStatus= function () {
        if (!vm.statuses()) {
            vm.filteredStatuses([]);
        }
        var filter = vm.searchTerm().toLowerCase();

        if (!filter) {
            vm.refresh();
            vm.filteredStatuses(vm.statuses());     

        }       
        var filtered = ko.utils.arrayFilter(vm.statuses(), function (item) {            

            var fields;
            if (vm.checkForWhichFilter() == 'A') {
                fields = ["carClasses"];
            }
            else if (vm.checkForWhichFilter() == 'F')
            {
                fields = ["fromDepotCodes"];
            }
            var i = fields.length;
            while (i--) {
                var prop = fields[i];
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(prop) && ko.isObservable(item[prop])) {
                    var strProp = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item[prop]).toString().toLocaleLowerCase();
                    if (item[prop]() && (strProp.indexOf(filter) !== -1)) {
                        oldAppvehicle = vm.applicableVehicle();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }            
            return false;
        });
        vm.statuses(filtered);
    };
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="form-control-static" data-bind="value:searchTerm ,valueUpdate: 'keyup',executeOnEnter:filterStatus" placeholder="Press enter to search..." />
```

For every search it needs to filter from the original list and not the already filtered list.

Answer (score 0):

You're filtering `vm.statuses`, and then saving the filtered result in `vm.statuses`. So, the next time you filter, you're filtering the previously filtered result. You should store the filtered results in a separate observable array so that the original, unfiltered array remains intact and can be filtered again. I see references to `vm.filteredStatuses` in your code, so maybe all you need to do is change:

```
vm.statuses(filtered);
```

to:

```
vm.filteredStatuses(filtered);
```

And obviously, show `filteredStatuses` in your UI instead of `statuses`.